# Select elements from powershell objects

Tags: powershell, hashtable

Hi everybody!

Short question:

Why does this work:

```
(Get-CimClass Win32_Share).CimClassMethods['Create'].Parameters
```

But this doesn’t:

```
(Get-CimClass Win32_Share).CimClassMethods.Create.Parameters
```

The same result can be achieved by:

```
   ((Get-CimClass Win32_Share).CimClassMethods|where-object {$_.name -match 'create'}).parameters
```

With the same logic I would expect that the same applies for:

```
(Get-command *help*)['get-help']
Or
(Get-command *help*)['cmdlet']
Or
(Get-childitem)['test.txt']
```

But it doesn’t. Only the method with where-object is possible here

Other considerations:

I know that this is should be the default way to retrive items from an hashtable and not pscustomobject but I also would like to better understand where else I can use this method. I searched the whole day on google but didn’t find anything.

Thanks in advance
Franco

Comment: It seems that `CimClassMethods` is an array instead of an object, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

The ***string*-based indexing (`['Create']`)** works, because the `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Internal.Data.CimMethodDeclarationCollection` type that it is applied to implements a **parameterized `Item` property  that has a *`[string]`*-typed parameter** (abstracted; verify with `Get-Member Item -InputObject Get-CimClass Win32_Share).CimClassMethods`):

```bash
# {get;} indicates that the property is read-only.
Item ParameterizedProperty <T> Item(string key) {get;}
```

<sup>Note: Strictly speaking, for something like `['Create']` to be accepted, it is sufficient for the `Item` property parameter to be *`[object]`*-typed, which is the case for the non-generic `[hashtable]` type, for instance.</sup>

For types with such a method, PowerShell, like C#, supports syntax `['Create']` as *syntactic sugar* for `.Item('Create')`, and the **implication** is that **a *key*-based item lookup is performed**.

*Typically*, such types also implement the `IDictionary` interface (e.g., `[hasthable]`), but that isn't the case here.

[`CimMethodDeclarationCollection`](https://github.com/PowerShell/MMI/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure/Internal/Data/CimMethodDeclarationCollection.cs) behaves similarly to an `[ordered]` [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables), in that it supports both *positional* (e.g, `[0]`) and *key*-based indexing (e.g., `['Create']`),<sup>[1]</sup> but with one crucial difference:

- PowerShell does *not* enumerate `IDictionary`-implementing types in the pipeline (you'll have to call `.GetEnumerator()` to achieve that), whereas `CimMethodDeclarationCollection` - due to not implementing `IDictionary` - *is* enumerated, like other collections such as arrays; that is, its elements / entries are sent one by one through the pipeline.

---

As for why something like the following doesn't work:

> (Get-command *help*)['get-help']

`Get-command *help*` outputs *multiple* objects, which `(...)` automatically collects in a *regular PowerShell array*, of type `[object[]]`.

`[object[]]` (based on [`System.Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array)), does *not* have the requisite parameterized property that would support `['get-help']` syntax - **arrays support only *positional* indexing (e.g. `[0]` to refer to the first element)**, based on a **parameterized `Item` property whose parameter is *`[int]`*-typed**, implemented as part of the [`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IList) interface (abstracted; verify with `Get-Member Item -InputObject @()`):

```bash
# Note: IList.Item indicates that the property is implemented
#       as part of the IList interface. 
#       {get;set;} indicates that the property is read-write.   
Item ParameterizedProperty <T> IList.Item(int index) {get;set;}
```

However, given PowerShell's [*member-access enumeration* feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) it is reasonable to expect `['get-help']` to then be applied to the *individual elements* of the array, given that's how it works with `.`, the [member-access operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#member-access-operator-) (e.g., `(Get-Command *help*).Name`).
As of PowerShell 7.2.4, however, only `.`, not also `["someKey"]` performs this enumeration; this surprising asymmetry is the subject of [GitHub issue #17514](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17514).

---

<sup>[1] An `[int]`-typed key doesn't *necessarily* imply *positional* semantics, but does in the context of implementing the `IList` or `ICollection` interfaces (or their generic equivalent).</sup>

Comment: Thank you a lot @mklement0 ! I make all the tests you suggested and I also discovered somenting new, I also read your interessant answer in [Ghithub issue #17541](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17514)